# Any shortcut for congruence modulo arithmetic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing simple question on congruence modulo arithmetic, and wondered if there is a shortcut for computing the same for below:

$9322 + 8321  \equiv ... \pmod{95}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce first:
$$9322 = 9500-178=9500-190+12 \equiv 12 \pmod{95}$$
$$8321 = 9500 - 1179 = 9500-950-229 = 9500-950-190-39 \equiv -39 \pmod{95}$$
Therefore
$$9322+8321 \equiv 12-39 = -27 \equiv 95-27 = 68 \pmod{95}.$$

**Alternate method for the above problem (also added in edit)**
Note that $1000\equiv 50 \pmod{95}$, and $100\equiv 5 \pmod{95}$,
so
$$9322+8321= (9+8)1000+(3+3)100+22+21 \equiv 17\cdot 50 + 6\cdot 5 + 43
\equiv 50 + 8\cdot 100 + 73 \equiv 50+40+73 \equiv 95-5 + 73 \equiv 68.$$

**Edit:** Based on your comments on the other answer, it seems like your question is more along the lines of: What are useful tricks for reducing large numbers to a number between $0$ and $n-1$ mod $n$ quickly?

In that case: I've demonstrated a general technique above, where you look at nice "round" multiples of your modulus, and repeatedly add/subtract them to reduce.

Relatedly, if you want to simplify a number $A$ mod $n$, and its easier to simplify modulo a multiple of $n$, $kn$, you can first simplify mod $kn$, then simplify the smaller number mod $n$. I'll demonstrate this below.

There are also several special techniques for certain numbers that take advantage of the fact that we express our numbers in base 10.

If $A=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i 10^i$ is the base 10 expression of a number (i.e. $a_i$ is the digit in the $10^i$s place), then there are a few nice moduluses (moduli?), $n$.

**Case 1:** $n=10^{m_0}$

In this case reduction mod $n$ is truncatation to $m_0$ digits, since for $i\ge m_0$, $a_i10^i$ is divisible by $n$. Therefore 
$$A\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{m_0-1} a_i10^i \pmod{10^{m_0}}.$$
As an example, $13434758 \equiv 758\pmod{10^3}$.

**Case 2:** $n=9$

In this case, $10\equiv 1$, so 
$$A= \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i10^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^m a_i \pmod{9},$$
i.e. $A$ is equivalent to the sum of its digits mod 9. This allows quick reductions, e.g. $13434758 \equiv 1+3+4+3+4+7+5+8 = 35 \equiv 3+5=8 \pmod{9}$.

**Case 3:** $n=11$

In this case, $10 \equiv -1$, so 
$$A= \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i10^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^m a_i(-1)^i \pmod{11},$$
i.e. $A$ is equivalent to the *alternating* sum of its digits mod 9. This also allows quick reductions, e.g. $13434758 \equiv -1+3-4+3-4+7-5+8 = 7  \pmod{11}$.

**Example for $n=2^{10}=1024$ using case 1.**

Suppose we want to reduce 1345922378472845723948573434758 mod 1024.
Since $2^{10}\mid 10^{10}$, we can first truncate the number until we're left with 10 digits to get 
$$1345922378472845723948573434758\equiv 8573434758 \pmod{1024},$$
then at that point, one could use long division or something to figure out the exact result. The point is you can save yourself a lot of work by first truncating using the fact that $2^{10}\mid 10^{10}$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for this. This is a trick for in general, and needs no more than basic efforts at remembering too.

Comment: You have covered broadly everything needed by me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it was helpful :)

Comment: I would also request some reference or google search key words to find the same online or in literature. Also, I am still unclear about case 1 being used to show example for binary number, particularly at the end where you show that $2^{10} | 10^{10}$.. I hope that you meant approximate division, please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I request some response to my earlier comment, as I am stuck.

Comment: @jiten I'm not sure about references, these tricks are just derived from the basic properties of modular arithmetic. There's a chance you might find similar things on AoPS though, since it's the sort of thing that'd be useful in contest math?

Comment: Also, since $2\mid 10$, $2^{10}\mid 10^{10}$. So I meant integer division. Then to reduce mod $2^{10}$, you can first reduce mod $10^{10}$, since $10^{10}\equiv 0 \pmod{2^{10}}$

Comment: Thanks  for your kind response.

Comment: @jiten It's not an approximation, it's because $10^{10}=(2\cdot 5)^{10}=2^{10}\cdot 5^{10}$.

Comment: Sorry, I read only first comment of yours.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the fact that $100 \equiv 5 \pmod{95}.$
Therefore $10000 = 100^2 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 25 \pmod{95},$ and
\begin{align}
9322 + 8321 &= 17643 \\
&= 10000 + 76 \times 100 + 43 \\
&\equiv 25 + 76 \times 5 + 43 \pmod{95} \\
&= 448  \\
&= 4 \times 100 + 48 \\
&\equiv 4 \times 5 + 48 \pmod{95} \\
&= 68.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the division algorithm on $9322+8321=17643$ to get $17643=185\cdot 95+68$. Therefore $68$ is your final answer.

Comment: but, if a trick that used smaller number of digits to be considered, as considering only the last 2 digits, then would be much better. I do not know when to apply such tricks and the logic behind them.

Comment: If your problem was mod 100, you could certainly ignore all but the last two digits. But in this case all the digits matter.

Comment: So, only powers of 10 have that properties, and any other like powers /multiples of 7, 9, 3.

Comment: Well, powers of 10 in particular because we represent our numbers in base 10